# Error while loading functional tests with intern

Tags: functional-testing, loader, intern, browserstack

I am trying to launch a functional test with `Intern`, using this command:

`./node_modules/.bin/intern-runner config=tests/intern`

,but I am having an error since yesterday, talking about the loader file.

[image]

Can somebody help me with this issue pleas? Thanks in advance.

MK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your intern config define for functionalSuites?

it should be `functionalSuites: [ 'tests/functional/index' ],`

Comment: thanks erikdstock,I will change it. May be it is space sensitive?

Comment: i find my erros, I was fogetting to remove the "< >" on the tunnelOptions. It works now, thanks!